# How much does string weigh?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, weight

I'm creating a rogue character and I've looked through all the equipment I can get with my class and decided to get the burglar's pack. Within this, I get 10 feet of string. I'm calculating my equipment's weight at the same time. I've looked through the D&D handbook 5e for the weight of string, but there is nothing. Does anyone know what the weight of string is?

Comment: Does your group actually even use weight in your games? Many groups don't bother with such petty bookkeeping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### String weighs a negligible amount.

"String" is a bit of a vague category, but I wouldn't say it would weigh any more per foot than, say, twine. Looking at a couple of listings online, 328' of twine is 2.89oz and 500' of another brand of twine is 6.3oz. That's a weight of ~0.0088 - ~0.013 ounces per foot, or up to an eighth of an ounce for 10' of twine. That's well below what would be modeled for encumbrance.

Answer (score 6):

### Negligible

10 feet of string are about 3 meters. **Common Sense** tells you that such an amount of string has a weight that is totally negligible. Even 3 meters of metal wire are in that area.

Many small items are without weight because you won't get encumbered by having said items in your pocket. 10-feet of string is one of these items.

If you really *must* have a weight: [Yarn for knitting](https://www.laughinghens.com/yarn-conversion-chart) can be measured in "meters per 100 grams". The thickest available wool is 40 meters per 100 grams, resulting in about 7.5 grams for that thickness, but you will most likely have a less thick yarn, but even if you had such super thick yarn, you are facing **less than 10 grams/a third of an ounce** for the 10 feet.

Comment: I live in the United States of America. Did you add the '3 meters' as clarification for those souls using the metric system?

Comment: @TieflingDragon84 the meter equivalent is required because of the meters-per-100-grams measurement. Which is the only measurement that gives you *somehow* a proper estimation for both thickness and weight in a wool supplier. Yarn Type is merely a thickness, just as Ply, Wraps per inch is a measurement for calculating knitting patterns and Tension/Gauge is for determining elasticity. In general you buy yarns by weight and thickness, at which point Meters-per-100-grams gives you the length of the bundle. And as said, those are *way thicker* than string, as it is knitting yarn.